# How to install RMySQL package for Windows?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Since binary file of RMySQL package is not available, I am not able to install it on Windows.

I looked up internet. I found this link. http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/comment-page-1/#comment-3123

I followed the instructions, but I am getting an ERROR.

This is the final output I get after

```
>install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')
```

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘DBI’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DBI_0.2-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 194699 bytes (190 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 190 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 161 Kb

installing *source* package 'DBI' ...
package 'DBI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
R
inst
preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for 'summary' from package 'base' in package 'DBI'
help
installing help indices
building package indices
installing vignettes
testing if installed package can be loaded
arch - i386
arch - x64
DONE (DBI)

installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** package 'RMySQL' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for $MYSQL_HOME... C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Program
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Program

CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
test: Files\MySQL\MySQL: unknown operand

** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames

gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\"/include    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o

****Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make:**  [RS-DBI.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'***

- removing 'C:/Users/admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/RMySQL'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\admin\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMvp14B/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMvp14B\downloaded_packages’

*I have written the error i am getting in bold. Please help me resolve it.
Thanks a lot.*

Comment: I'm getting a `./configure.win: line 10: test: too many arguments
` on 64 bit R in W7... Haven't been able to get this thing working for years now.

Comment: [refer this to install `RMySQL` for windows](http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/)

Answer (score 5):

- Go to System->Advanced->Enviroment Variables, press New and Enter
  Variable name as MYSQL_HOME and Variable values as `C:/Program
  Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/`, and  **notice that it is "/" not "\"**
- Copy `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.dll` to
  `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin` and **create C:/Program
  Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/opt** folder and **copy C:/Program
  Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.lib** to the **opt** folder
- Run `install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')`

In some instances you might need to restart your PC.

Comment: Great Odin's Raven - you just saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Please following the instruction here: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL
I believe you missed the step 3

> **3. Edit or create the file Renviron.site and add the variable MYSQL_HOME** which contains the location of your MySQL install. The
>   file typically isn't created when installing R, so you may need to
>   create it yourself. You will want to place it under the /etc directory
>   in your R Home area. If you don't know where that is, you can issue
>   R.home() at your R prompt. You will be adding a variable named
>   MYSQL_HOME in variable=value syntax.

Here's an example:

```
Location of Renviron.site: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-2.11~1.0/etc/Renviron.site 
Content is: MYSQL_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLS~1.0/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue as well.  It took me a while to understand:

1. that I needed to manually create a text file named **Renviron.site** in the proper Windows directory, and,
2. that the manually created **Renviron.site** file needed to contain the definition of the **MYSQL_HOME** variable.

Here is my example from Windows 10 and R version 3.2.2:

1. I issued the command **R.home()** at the R prompt in R Studio:

   ```
   R.home()
   [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2"
   ```
2. With that information, I navigated to the **etc** folder in Windows:

   ```
    C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\etc
   ```
3. I placed a manually created text file called **Renviron.site** within this directory (the "etc" folder).  The only data in the **Renviron.site** text file is the following:

   ```
   MYSQL_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLS~1.2/
   ```

   (I wasn't sure whether to use ~1.0 or ~1.2 here based on the output from the R.home() command in R, but, this seemed to work)
4. Once the file was saved, I restarted R and I was able to install the RMySQL package in R.